# Unity Object Movement - Object Only Goes Down and Right?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, unityscript

I have been working on a Unity Game project, and my sprite will only move down and to the right. Here is my current script:

```
#pragma strict
function Update (){
    var ship = GetComponent(Rigidbody2D);
    var speed = 10;
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
        ship.velocity.y = speed;
    }else {
        ship.velocity.y = 0;
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
        ship.velocity.x = -1 * speed;
    }else {
        ship.velocity.x = 0;
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
        ship.velocity.y = -1 * speed;
    }else {
        ship.velocity.y = 0;
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
        ship.velocity.x = speed;
    }else {
        ship.velocity.x = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself, the problem was that I was setting velocity to 0 even when I hadn't tested for the other keys first.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use  Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") and Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) with this you avoid a lot of code and it's better.

And you don't need instantiate the rigidbody2D component, just do:

`rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(speed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), speed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));`

Also, I don't see any failure on you code, Do you have another script in your object? or How do you have your rigidbody2D in the object?